# Drive (other than cars or buses)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was wondering if it correct to use drive when speaking of trains, tanks, ships, spaceships, airplanes, boats?

- To drive a tank
- To drive an airplane
- To drive a train
- To drive a boat
- To drive a spaceship
- To drive a ship

Are they correct? Or should some other verb be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use different verbs, depending on the medium that the vehicle moves over/through.  There are often differences between everyday terms and military terms.  Very often, the verb is also used as a title for the person who is in control of the vehicle.

The generic verb for controlling a vehicle is '[operate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operate)', but it's usually not idiomatic or everyday language.

Ground vehicles (car, bus, tank) we '[drive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive)'.

Trains we also 'drive', but the person who drives a train may be called an 'engineer', a 'train driver', an 'engine driver', or an 'engine operator'.

Vehicles on or in water (boat, ship, submarine) we '[sail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sail)' - whether the ship uses sails or an engine.  When on a river or in a harbor, we may also say '[pilot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilot)'.  A term used in the military is '[conn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conn)'.

Vehicles in the air (airplane, glider) we '[fly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fly)' or 'pilot'.

Vehicles in space that are actively controlled (capsule, shuttle) are treated like vehicles in the air - we 'fly' or 'pilot' them.  Vehicles in space that have only limited propulsion (space stations) are commanded, and when they are put into motion they are '[maneuvered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maneuver)'.

Comment: Jesus, so difficult. So many words you have to remember. What about the word **"control"**? Can it apply to any of the above?

Comment: It's not any better in Russian, is it?  You have a dozen different words for "to go".  Control doesn't work.  "I drive to work every morning" is ok; "I control to work every morning" is not.  "I know how to drive a bus" and "I know how to control a bus" are closer, but control is still unnatural.

Comment: Pilot would work for a lot of the larger vehicles (tanks, ships, planes, submarines), except for trains because you don't steer them. I probably would use "operate" for trains instead of drive, but "he drives a train" is fine too.

Comment: @JohnFeltz It's a lot easier in Russian than in English. Ты можешь управлять лошадью (самолётом, танком, машиной, поездом, кораблём, лодкой, космическим кораблём, бронетранспортёром, подлодкой, велосипедом, мотоциклом, шаттлом, космической станцией, трактором)? We have one word for everything **"control"**.

Comment: @JohnFeltz If we speak of movement then a bit harder but still easy.

Comment: One minor clarification:  a bicycle or motorcycle is also a ground vehicle, but you don't drive it, you *ride* it.

Comment: @stangdon Good catch!

Comment: @stangdon: You can also ***ride*** a horse, etc., as well as a bike (motorised or not). For all of those we normally assume there's only one person involved (he's both a passive *passenger* and actively *controlling* the "conveyance"). But ***ride a bus***, for example, would almost always only imply the passenger sense, not the controller.

Comment: @SovereignSun  You can ask "Who's in control of the plane?" and expect a response like "The co-pilot is flying it right now".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Good point about *driving* a bus vs. *riding* a bus!  One other odd minor case occurred to me: people sometimes refer to *riding* a tractor instead of *driving* a tractor (perhaps because, like a motorcycle, you're on the outside/on top of it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You *steer* a barge (certainly, a horse-drawn one).

Comment: @stangdon: Another one that seems a bit odd is that *He **takes** the bus to work every day* sounds fine, whereas *He takes the car to work every day* doesn't really sit well with me. And that's not to mention the fact that obviously it's the bus (or train) that "takes, carries, transports" him to work, not the other way around. Besides verbification, idiomacy also weirds language! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers My husband does sometimes ask me if he can *take* my car instead of his when he's heading somewhere specific.

Comment: @ColleenV: I'm in two minds as to whether *Can I take your car this morning?* implies ***use*** or ***deprive** [you of]* it. But on reflection I must accept that *Can I take your car **to work** this morning?* doesn't grate on me so much as my own example above.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just thought of another situation. "Do you need a ride to the party? No, I'm going to take my car because I have to leave early. " Take changes the emphasis from the driver to the vehicle somehow.

Comment: @ColleenV: Very true. In contexts like yours it's a particularly natural usage, because if you ***took*** your car, *you've still got it with you* at the destination (unlike if you *took a **cab*** or *a **bus***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So I've recently discovered the term deitic and I'm a bit obsessed with the usages of come, take, give, et. al.. If I changed your example of *He takes the car to work every day* to *He takes his car to work every day*, does it sit better with you?

Comment: @ColleenV: Haha! When I first mentioned *He takes the car to work every day* above, I recall that I actually wrote ***his** car* initially, then changed it to ***the** car* within the edit grace period because I thought that better supported what I was saying (in short, ***his*** does indeed sit better with me for ***car***). But it's precisely the opposite with, say, *I take **the/my** local bus to work*, so I'm not sure if there's really any consistent "logic" here. Certainly OP isn't likely to get a very clear-cut set of rules defining "correct" usages in this area.